# Gaps and Island - Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to group my data by: State, Product, Edition, LG_SG, Area, and Area Factor. I then want to attach the minimum start date and the maximum end date to the record. I have a Gaps and Island issue though. If you look at the data, the .8428 shows up in two blocks that are not in chronological order. How do I solve this problem in Access?

Here is my current data.

```
state   start_date  end_date    product edition lg_sg   area    area_factor
IL  10/1/2010   11/1/2010   PPO 6   SG  1   0.86
IL  11/1/2010   12/1/2010   PPO 6   SG  1   0.86
IL  12/1/2010   1/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.86
IL  1/1/2011    2/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  2/1/2011    3/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  3/1/2011    4/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  4/1/2011    5/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  5/1/2011    6/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  6/1/2011    7/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  7/1/2011    8/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  8/1/2011    9/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  9/1/2011    10/1/2011   PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  10/1/2011   11/1/2011   PPO 6   SG  1   0.825944
IL  11/1/2011   12/1/2011   PPO 6   SG  1   0.825944
IL  12/1/2011   1/1/2012    PPO 6   SG  1   0.825944
IL  1/1/2012    2/1/2012    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  2/1/2012    3/1/2012    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  3/1/2012    4/1/2012    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  4/1/2012    5/1/2012    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
```

I would like it to look like this.

```
state   start_date  end_date    product edition lg_sg   area    area_factor
IL  10/1/2010   1/1/2011    PPO 6   SG  1   0.86
IL  1/1/2011    10/1/2011   PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
IL  10/1/2011   1/1/2012    PPO 6   SG  1   0.825944
IL  1/1/2012    5/1/2012    PPO 6   SG  1   0.8428
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Add in your query: `Group By Year(start_date), area_factor`.

Comment: Will this work in every scenario though? I have massive table and this is only a small portion that illustrates my idea. Won't adding the "Year(start_date)" only work if they happen to fall in distinct years? @Gustav

Comment: 1 approach would be to write a vb script to summarize the data - is that an option?  A 2nd approach might work if you can put an autonumber ID field in the file to facilitate matching data with the prior record - is that an option?

Comment: @DonGeorge I can write a vb script. I know how to do that but was hoping to solve this with a query. I do have an index on the entire table and the records are unique so I could probably ad an autonumber ID. Can you expand on what I would do if I went this route?

Comment: Don't know. We only have your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a start

```
SELECT data.state, data.start_date, data.product, data.edition, data.lg_sg, data.area, data.area_factor, data_1.area_factor AS previous
FROM data LEFT JOIN data AS data_1 ON data.start_date = data_1.end_date
WHERE (((data_1.area_factor) Is Null Or (data_1.area_factor)<>[data].[area_factor]));
```

It gives you the start date for each range, but not the end date.  If you're using this as a reference to search for a specific date, it might be enough - you can search for the last record that's less than or equal to your search date, without needing the end date.

I was initially thinking that an auto number field would help ID the end date, but now I'm not sure.  This query already does the work I would have done with an auto number field, and I don't quite see how to get the end date yet.

UPDATE:  This isn't elegant, but I can do it in a few steps:
Save the query above as StartDates.  Then use this query to find the next start date for the same area_factors:

```
SELECT StartDates.state, StartDates.start_date, StartDates.product, StartDates.edition, StartDates.lg_sg, StartDates.area, StartDates.area_factor, (select min(start_date) from StartDates T where T.area_factor=StartDates.area_factor and T.start_date>StartDates.start_date) AS [Next]
FROM StartDates
ORDER BY StartDates.start_date;
```

Save this as NextDates, then use this final query to get the answer:

```
SELECT NextDates.state, NextDates.start_date, Max(data.end_date) AS end_date, NextDates.product, NextDates.edition, NextDates.lg_sg, NextDates.area, NextDates.area_factor
    FROM NextDates INNER JOIN data ON NextDates.area_factor = data.area_factor
    WHERE (((data.start_date)<[next])) OR (((NextDates.Next) Is Null))
    GROUP BY NextDates.state, NextDates.start_date, NextDates.product, NextDates.edition, NextDates.lg_sg, NextDates.area, NextDates.area_factor;
```

Depending on the data, you made need to add joins to restrict the logic to matching states, or products, or other field(s).

Comment: The end date is not important. The end date is always exactly one month after the start date. I have a separate query that adds the end date in by using this logic. I can adjust the field after I use the query you just provided.

Comment: OK, good - but the end date on your expected output isn't the start date + 1 month.  Still, glad this starting point helped.

Comment: I preemptively left my comment before running your query. I realized that after I ran it and noticed the same issue.

Comment: @MBrady - just curious, did this work out for you or are there still problems?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the autonumber id field (assuming one exists) to create a distinct groups, *grp*, and then aggregate in outer query:

```
SELECT r.state, Min(r.start_date) as min_start_date, Max(r.end_date) as 
       max_end_date, r.product, r.edition, r.lg_sg, Max(r.area) as max_area, 
       r.area_factor
FROM
  (SELECT *,
            (SELECT max(id) FROM GapsIslandsTable sub 
             WHERE sub.area_factor = g.area_factor 
               AND Year(sub.start_date) = Year(g.start_date)) as grp
   FROM GapsIslandsTable g) r

GROUP BY r.state, r.product, r.edition, r.lg_sg, r.area_factor, r.grp

-- state    min_start_date  max_end_date    product edition lg_sg   max_area   area_factor
-- IL            10/1/2011      1/1/2012        PPO       6    SG          1      0.825944 
-- IL             1/1/2011     10/1/2011        PPO       6    SG          1        0.8428 
-- IL             1/1/2012      5/1/2012        PPO       6    SG          1        0.8428 
-- IL            10/1/2010      1/1/2011        PPO       6    SG          1          0.86
```